# firebase: QuerySnapShot is not null but occurs "undefined" when use it

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use firestore on Firebase.
My code is below.

```
db.collection("notifications").where("type", "==", "like_comment").where("comment_ref", "==", like_snap.data().comment_ref).get().then((notice) => {
    if(notice.docs[0]) {
      notice.docs[0].ref.update({
        updated_at: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })
      .then(() => {
        ----
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.warn(error)
      });
    } else {
        ----
    }
  })
})
.catch((error: any) => {
  console.warn(error)
})
```

notice is not null or undefined but when I use it the error below occurs.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Someone knows the reason?

Comment: What is the value of `like_snap.data().comment_ref`?

Comment: reference data and it is not null.

Comment: The only place you are using `get()` in the code you've shown will definitely never be undefined.  Perhaps you are not showing all the relevant code.